# Unable to recompile jsps

Tags: aem, apache-felix, sling

I am working on CQ5.6.1 version and trying to recompile jsp files. When I try to hit http://localhost:4502/system/console/slingjsp . I am getting 404 error as below. Any Idea where the problem is?

```
The requested page was not found. If you are not forwarded in 3 seconds to the Web Console, please click here
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a running CQ 5 instance but I think that it didn't had the FSClassLoader that handles the compiled JSP in my AEM 6.1 instance. So you probably receive a 404 because this plugin is not be installed.

If you want to find more about your concrete issue `tail` the `error.log` file and also you may check that the following bundles are in the `Active` state:

- Apache Sling JSP Tag Library
- Apache Sling Scripting Core
- Apache Sling Scripting Implementation API
- Apache Sling Scripting Java Support
- Apache Sling Scripting JavaScript Support
- Apache Sling Scripting JSP Support
- Apache Sling Scripting JST Support

As a response to your question, in CQ 5 you can achieve what you want by manually deleting the compiled nodes found in the repository at  `/var/classes` and `/var/clientlibs`.